# Using AppCheck with Flutter, getting permission-denied for Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-app-check

I've implemented AppCheck using the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers

I've verified that I call this (after firebase initiazlization):
`await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();`

When testing my app locally, on iOS emulator, I get permission-denied when trying to read / write to Firestore.

More details:

1. Trying to read documents from Firestore (used to work before AppCheck enforcement)
2. DB security rules allow read / write to authenticated users who made the request (tested in "Rules Playground" and used to work before AppCheck enforcement)

Do I need to setup anything in order to test my app on the emulator?
Am I missing anything?
Does it have anything to do with this (no flutter mentioned there):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the code that doesn't work the way you expect, your security rules, and the steps you take to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've added (under "More details") some more info. I hope it helps. I'll gladly add any other relevant info

Comment: Please read my previous comment again for things to add to the question.  We can't reproduce this given the information you've shown so far.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have read the original comment, but it's a bit of an issue to provide the code and the security rules since they are specific to my DB (I prefer not to expose my DB structure and I guess I won't help you much)...
Is it possible that I get these issue since I run my app with a debug version on iOS emulator?

Comment: If we can't see your code, then we won't be able to tell if you're doing something wrong.  On Stack Overflow, it's expected that questions provide a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile? I just opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72908766/2154784

Comment: It works for me on the device itself, in release, not on the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Use the debug provider and add a debug token to Firebase.

See [Use App Check with the debug provider with Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider).

Something like this for iOS:

```
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)

        FirebaseApp.configure()
...
```

Comment: I suspect that's the problem. It's unclear to me how to add the Swift / Objective-C code shown there in my Flutter app...