# Permission Denied Error in Android Emulator when Enforcing App Check for Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-emulator, firebase-app-check

After spending hours for getting App Check working on the physical devices (iOS and Android) of my Flutter app i also tried the provided documentation steps in order to get it working for Android emulator as well.
Whatever i try i always get the following error for all my listening streams that are invoked against the Firestore database when App Check is enforced:

```
W/Firestore( 5612): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(Contract where isArchive==false and contractorId==myContractorId order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

I've added the depencency in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0'
}
```

and have overridden onCreate in MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            //Log.d("MainActivity", "debug mode entered")
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp( /*context=*/this)
            val firebaseAppCheck: FirebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance())
        } else {
            //Log.d("MainActivity", "else mode entered")
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

The resulting debug token was added successfully to the list of debug tokens in Firebase console.
All Firestore collection rules look like the following example rule:

```
match /Contractor/{contractor} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

Activating App Check in the Flutter main function looks like this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
```

Without enforced App Check i don't have any problems running the Flutter app on my Android emulator.
All Firebase plugins are the most recent ones.
What else can i try or change in order to get this working?
If it doesn't work also on Android emulators we will give up using App Check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in cloud function:

```js
  if (context.app == undefined && !process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "failed-precondition",
        "The function must be called from an App-Check verified app.");
  }
```

You need to add this code:

```
!process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR
```

Comment: You need to remove that code after you are done experimenting with Android emulator and started to test it on real device for production. Hope it works.

Comment: Actually i do work and test all the time on emulators _and_ real devices in parallel. Therefore i don't think that your code part mentioned would be a solution for my work. But thank you.